# hector quadrotor - amcl navigation

Tags: ros, gazebo, 2d-mapping, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
I would like to implement the 2d navigation (fixed altitude)  of amcl (like turtlebot3, that I used a lot)
on a simulated quadrotor in Gazebo.
The map is known (already built).
How can I send 2d navigation goals to the quadrotor?
Any help?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278302/hector-quadrotor---amcl-navigation/) by [polde](https://answers.ros.org/users/32229/polde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [navigation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials). If you get `amcl` working with your drone, then I can't imagine that it would be any different than how the tutorials describe.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [polde](https://answers.ros.org/users/32229/polde/) on 2017-12-29**:
Thank you!
I already tried some package from Wil Seby (https://github.com/wilselby/ROS_quadrotor_simulator) but I had some problem using it from 'high level'.
Do you think that build it from zero is a good idea?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-29**:
What do you mean by "high level" and "build it from zero?"